# Convert from AIFF to AAC using Apple API only

Tags: objective-c, aac

I am creating a movie file using QTMovie from QTKit and everything's working nicely. The only problem I have is that the audio in the resulting MOV file is just the raw AIFF hence the file size is larger than I'd like. I've seen plenty about third party libraries capable of encoding to AAC but are there any Apple APIs which I can call to do this job? I don't mind converting the AIFF to AAC prior to adding it to my QTMovie or having the encoding done as part of writing the QTMovie to disk.

Comment: are you capturing the video, or opening it from a file?

Comment: I am creating a movie using initToWritableFile and then adding images using addImage:forDuration:withAttributes:. Next I open the AIFF file as another QTMovie, extract the audio track and add it to the first movie using insertSegmentOfTrack:timeRange:atTime:. Finally I save the complete movie to a new file (setting the QTMovieFlatten attribute to YES) using writeToFile:withAttributes:error:. My guess is that either I will need to convert the loaded AIFF file and add a track containing AAC audio to my movie or the call to save the complete movie will need some extra attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually easily achievable using QTKit. I just needed to set the QTMovieExportType to 'mpg4' and QTMovieExport to be YES when calling writeToFile:withAttributes:.